# Parent Child Components and cross page functionality

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a bank application for an online course. I am using React and my app needs to have a balance page, withdraw page and deposit page. I am unable to get the balance to transfer from the deposit page to the withdraw page, nor have it show on the balance page. Also, every time I navigate to a different page after depositing an amount in the deposit page and come back to the deposit.js the balance resets to 0. Please take a look to my code below and advice me.

Deposit.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { CardContext } from './CardContext';

const ATMDeposit = ({ onChange }) => {
  
  return (
    <label className="label huge">
      <input type="number" width="200" onChange={onChange} />
      <input type="submit" width="200" value="Deposit" />
    </label>
  );
};

const Account = () => {
  const [deposit, setDeposit] = useState(0); // state of this transaction
  const [totalState, setTotalState] = useState(0);
  let blc = useState(CardContext) 
 
  let status = `Account Balance $ ${totalState} `;

  const handleChange = event => {
    console.log(`handleChange ${event.target.value}`);
    setDeposit(Number(event.target.value));
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    let newTotal = totalState + deposit;
    setTotalState(newTotal);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Card 
      bgcolor="primary"
      header="Deposit"
      body={(
        <>
          <h1 id="total">{status}</h1>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <ATMDeposit onChange={handleChange} />
          </form>
        </>
        )}
    />
  )
}; 

export default Account;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import CreateAccount from './Createaccount';
import Login from './Login';
import Deposit from './Deposit';
import Withdraw from './Withdraw';
import Balance from './Balance';
import AllData from './Alldata';
import Home from './Home';
import { CardContext } from "./CardContext";
import { useState } from 'react';
import ATMDeposit from './Deposit';


const App = () => {
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
    <CardContext.Provider value={{users: [], balance: []}}>
      <Navbar className='container'/>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
              <Route path="/Home" element={<Home/>} />
              <Route path="/Create-account" element={<CreateAccount/>} />
              <Route path="/Login" element={<Login/>} />
              <Route path="/Deposit" element={<ATMDeposit/>} />
              <Route path="/Withdraw" element={<Withdraw/>} />
              <Route path="/Balance" element={<Balance/>} />
              <Route path="/All-data" element={<AllData/>} />
          </Routes>
      </CardContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import CreateAccount from './Createaccount';
import Login from './Login';
import Deposit from './Deposit';
import Withdraw from './Withdraw';
import Balance from './Balance';
import AllData from './Alldata';
import Home from './Home';
import { CardContext } from "./CardContext";
import { useState } from 'react';
import ATMDeposit from './Deposit';


const App = () => {
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
    <CardContext.Provider value={{users: [], balance: []}}>
      <Navbar className='container'/>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
              <Route path="/Home" element={<Home/>} />
              <Route path="/Create-account" element={<CreateAccount/>} />
              <Route path="/Login" element={<Login/>} />
              <Route path="/Deposit" element={<ATMDeposit/>} />
              <Route path="/Withdraw" element={<Withdraw/>} />
              <Route path="/Balance" element={<Balance/>} />
              <Route path="/All-data" element={<AllData/>} />
          </Routes>
      </CardContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: State is cleared when a component is unmounted. You have to store this data on the server or use indexed db or local storage